# How to use a dropdown list an Entity Framework MVC Web App (VB.net)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, scaffolding

I am absolute beginner.

What I want is my view page to have a dropdown as opposed to free text.

Model:

```
Partial Public Class DATAMART
    <StringLength(18)>
    Public Property CollaboartionRequestIdSfdcBk As String

    <Key>
    <StringLength(20)>
    Public Property Name As String
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.ProductName, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ProductName, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ProductName, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

I am quite certain something like dropdownlist is involved, but where do the data options come from??

Comment: There is a [`DropDownListFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method that you can use much like that `EditorFor` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not matching with the view, are you using ProductName or Name ? Here is an example of code that work well, just try it :

Use Html Helper with DropDownList  and ViewData:

In your controller ( HomeController.vb ):

```
Public Function ShowMyDropDown() As ActionResult
    Dim List1 As List(Of SelectListItem) = New List(Of SelectListItem) From {
        New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Red", .Value = 1},
        New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Green", .Value = 2},
        New SelectListItem With {.Text = "Blue", .Value = 3}
    }

    ViewData("List1") = New SelectList(List1, "Value", "Text", 2)  '2 is default selected value

    Return View()
End Function
```

In your View  ( ShowMyDropDown.vbhtml ):

```
@Html.DropDownList("Colors", TryCast(ViewData("List1"), SelectList), "Select a color", htmlAttributes:=New With {Key .class = "form-control"})
```

This example is just that you can start to understand the basic, and then try to explain more what you need , if you can't achieve your need and you need with models i will add an edit.